# Why is there a constructor accepting both initializer_list and a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17

I notice that `std::optional`, `std::variant`, `std::any` all have constructors accepting **both** `std::initializer_list` and `args...` at the same time.

[std::optional ctor (7)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional)

[std::any ctor (6)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any)

[std::variant ctor (8)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant)

Why is there such a constructor? What use case does it support?

Comment: The page you linked has an example.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about the example of std::optional?
    // calls std::string( initializer_list<CharT> ) constructor
    std::optional<std::string> o4(std::in_place, {'a', 'b', 'c'});  Sure,it's ok. But I am wondering why there is a "Args...",after initializer_list. I mean,just Args.. is ok,just initializer_list is ok, why both?

Comment: "*Why both*" is not the same question as "*How to use it*", which has an obvious answer. I suggest you rephrase to ask what you actually want to know.

Comment: Thanks. I rephrased the title. I'm not a native speaker, if you think it's still not good, please help me to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is a stupid question.

Thank all of you for helping me edit the question.

It's quite ok that using both initializer_list and parameter pack.

For example, std::vector has a constructor accepting initializer_list and allocator.

And I tested, that seems the answer.

```
std::variant<std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>> v(std::in_place_index<0>,{1,2,3,4},std::allocator<int>());

for(int i: std::get<0>(v))
{
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

And there is another question, why initializer_list has to be specially separated from other template arguments. I guess I can find it in somewhere else.